# XNA есть ли будущее? Какие альтернативы?

Tags: xna, c#, directx

Увы не обнаружил XNA для VS Desktop 2012 Express.

Нашел массу хаков, но они не внушают доверия.

Кто нибудь в курсе MS забил на XNA? Или все таки этот фреймворк будет развиваться?

Возможно это только слухи, но есть информация что MS не будет делать XNA для Desktop и оставит ее только для мобильников и XBOX.

Если нет, какие есть альтернативы? Насколько я понимаю есть какие то средства для использования DirectX в C#? Подскажите какие?

Comment: Если интересует связка DirectX10(11, 9) и WPF, то у меня есть своя наработка. Работает быстро и без косяков, могу поделиться. semenvx27@yadex.ru. (Рендерит устройство на текстуру и биндит ее на изображение WPF без копирования.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Недавняя статья на хабре пролила свет на вопрос:
[Введение в разработку игр для Windows 8 с использованием XNA и MonoGame](http://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/164217/).

Если точнее: есть открытая разработка - MonoGame (аналог XNA).
Программирование на MonoGame позволяет почти не менять код для XNA.
Так что ее можно считать полной альтернативой.

В ответах так же был озвучен SharpDX, однако есть и другие:

- EaselJS
- ImpactJS
- Construct2
- Delta Engine
- Unigine
- Ogre Engine
- Cocos2D
- Bepu Physics
- Jitter Physics
- Box2DX

Answer (score 10):

В vs12 xna есть, но пока что только для windows phone. Скорее всего, позже сделают и для desktop'ов.

Также советую присмотреться к [SharpDX](http://www.sharpdx.org/)

Comment: Спасибо, интересная информация. Хотелось бы чтобы все же появилась XNA для десктопа. Шарп тоже что то интересное надо посмотреть)

Answer (score 6):

XNA [добавляет гигантский оверхед](http://code4k.blogspot.ru/2011/03/benchmarking-cnet-direct3d-11-apis-vs.html) по сравнению с нативным DirectX. Если нужно писать на C#, то правильным выбором будет SharpDX.